# search by full text does not return all results

Tags: mysql, laravel, postgresql

I have the following table, with these columns

| first_name | last_name |
| --- | --- |
| maria | herrera |
| maria | de herrera |

I want to get all the records that have the word "herrera",for which I do the following query

```
$query = OrgClient::whereRaw("CONCAT(org_clients.first_name,' ',org_clients.last_name)  Ilike ?",["%maria herrera%"])->get();
```

however this only returns 1 row

| first_name | last_name |
| --- | --- |
| maria | herrera |

I need it to return both, since both names have the word "herrera", how could this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add another wildcard

```
["%maria %herrera%"]
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not a good idea to search this way, cause functions ignoring indexes.

Separate string by whitespace and add multiple conditions

```php
$words = explode(' ', $searchString);

OrgClient::where(function ($query) use ($words) {
  foreach ($words as $w) {
    // note we dont use first %
    $query->orWhere('org_clients.first_name', 'like', $w . '%');
    $query->orWhere('org_clients.last_name', 'like', $w . '%');
  }
});
```